# Why are my (ggplot2) plot values different from what is in my dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm struggling with something here: my ggplot graph values do not match what I have in the data. Any ideas, please? Here's my code:

```
# data
gar <– structure(list(Day = c("22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", 
"23-02-2023", "23-02-2023", "23-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", 
"24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "28-02-2023", 
"28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", 
"22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", "23-02-2023", "23-02-2023", 
"24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "27-02-2023", 
"28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", 
"22-02-2023", "22-02-2023", "23-02-2023", "23-02-2023", "24-02-2023", 
"24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "28-02-2023", 
"28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "28-02-2023", "22-02-2023", 
"23-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "24-02-2023", "27-02-2023", "28-02-2023"
), Behaviour = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Red", 
"Amber", "Green", "Asleep"), class = "factor"), Start = c("12:00", 
"17:00", "21:00", "09:00", "18:00", "21:00", "09:00", "14:00", 
"18:00", "20:00", "10:00", "18:00", "12:00", "17:00", "19:00", 
"00:00", "02:00", "04:00", "09:00", "15:00", "00:00", "06:00", 
"22:00", "06:00", "16:00", "22:00", "06:00", "21:00", "06:00", 
"15:00", "22:00", "07:00", "11:00", "16:00", "20:00", "08:00", 
"20:00", "07:00", "15:00", "17:00", "09:00", "23:00", "07:00", 
"11:00", "16:00", "18:00", "20:00", "13:00", "17:00", "11:00", 
"19:00", "16:00", "08:00"), End = c("15:00", "20:00", "00:00", 
"17:00", "20:00", "22:00", "11:00", "15:00", "19:00", "22:00", 
"16:00", "21:00", "15:00", "18:00", "20:00", "01:00", "03:00", 
"05:00", "11:00", "16:00", "06:00", "08:00", "06:00", "07:00", 
"17:00", "06:00", "09:00", "06:00", "07:00", "16:00", "06:00", 
"09:00", "12:00", "17:00", "21:00", "09:00", "21:00", "09:00", 
"16:00", "18:00", "10:00", "00:00", "08:00", "12:00", "17:00", 
"19:00", "22:00", "14:00", "19:00", "14:00", "20:00", "18:00", 
"11:00")), row.names = c(NA, -53L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

# convert the column to POSIXlt & date format
gar$Start <- as.POSIXlt(gar$Start)
gar$End <- as.POSIXlt(gar$End)
gar$Day <- as.Date(gar$Day)

# convert Behaviour as factor
gar$Behaviour <- as.factor(gar$Behaviour)

# extract the time component using the format "%H:%M" & "%d-%m-%Y"
gar$Start <- format(gar$Start, "%H:%M")
gar$End <- format(gar$End, "%H:%M")
gar$Day <- format(gar$Day, "%d-%m-%Y")

# arrange order of variables
gar <- gar %>%
  arrange(Behaviour) %>%
  mutate(Behaviour = factor(Behaviour, 
                       levels=c("Red",
                                "Amber",
                                "Green",
                                "Asleep"))) 

# plot
ggplot(gar, aes(colour=Behaviour)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Start, xmax = End, ymin = Behaviour, ymax = Behaviour)) +
  facet_wrap(~Day, ncol = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Start, 
                   xend = End, 
                   y = Behaviour,
                   yend = Behaviour), size=6) +
  xlab("Duration") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(Red = "red", 
                                 Green = "#99CC33", 
                                 Amber = "#FFCC00", 
                                 Asleep = "gray" )) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("\n\nDuration") + ylab("Behaviour\n\n")
```

Then, I get the attached image.

[image]

However, you will see that the value of Amber on the 22-02-2023 isn't what the data specifies. The exact same happens to other categories on other days...

Any help would be very much appreciated, Thank you!

Details are described above.

Comment: Are you sure `as.POSIXlt(gar$Start)` works the way you expect? Rather use `readr::parse_time(gar$Start)`

Comment: Hi @AndreWildberg, thanks. The `readr::parse_time(gar$Start)` doesn't work. It seems to work only with characters rather than POISXlt. Here's the error message:

`Error in parse_vector(x, col_time(format), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) :` 
  `is.character(x) is not TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have some `End` times that are 00:00. But since you are plotting time as a character variable, 00:00 is at the left hand side of your plot. The third entry for Amber starts at 21:00 then goes all the way back to 00:00 on the same day.

I'd normally advise sticking to using actual date-times for plotting date-times, but the obvious fix here is to change any End values of 00:00 to 24:00

```r
gar %>%
  mutate(End = ifelse(End == "00:00", "24:00", End)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(colour=Behaviour)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Start, xmax = End, ymin = Behaviour, 
                ymax = Behaviour)) +
  facet_wrap(~Day, ncol = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Start, 
                   xend = End, 
                   y = Behaviour,
                   yend = Behaviour), size=6) +
  xlab("Duration") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(Red = "red", 
                                 Green = "#99CC33", 
                                 Amber = "#FFCC00", 
                                 Asleep = "gray" )) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("\n\nDuration") + 
  ylab("Behaviour\n\n")
```

[image]

It may be better to convert the time to integer hours and use a custom labelling function on the x axis:

```r
gar %>%
  mutate(End = as.numeric(substr(End, 1, 2)),
         Start = as.numeric(substr(Start, 1, 2)),
         End = ifelse(End == 0, 24, End)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(colour = Behaviour)) +
  facet_wrap(~Day, ncol = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = Behaviour,
                   yend = Behaviour), size = 6) +
  scale_x_continuous("Duration", breaks = 0:24,
                     labels = ~sprintf("%02d:00", .x %% 24)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(Red = "red", 
                                 Green = "#99CC33", 
                                 Amber = "#FFCC00", 
                                 Asleep = "gray" )) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible, thanks @AllanCameron! Although I can see the problem is rectified for Amber, Asleep continues with the same issue. I've made some changes in the data: where Asleep was from 22:00 to 06:00, for example, I split it into two: from 22:00-29:59:59, and from 00:00-06:00, and it worked perfectly. Thanks again – Highly highly appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

@AllanCameron's answer is correct. This suggestion for streamlining your data processing pipeline ought to be a comment but is a bit too long ... (it does technically solve the problem, but doesn't add anything conceptual to the previous answer).

```r
library(tidyverse)
gar <- (gar
    |> mutate(
           across(End,  ~ ifelse(. == "00:00", "24:00", .)),
           across(c(Start, End), readr::parse_time),
           across(Day, ~ readr::parse_date(., format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
           across(Behaviour, ~ factor(., levels=c("Red",
                                                     "Amber",
                                                     "Green",
                                                     "Asleep")))
              )
)
```